# Why Is this X11 code not capturing mouse events?

Tags: c++, linux, x11

I'm attempting to use `XGrabPointer` to grab pointer events, for a color picker that is part of a much bigger application, and I've set a mask to capture button press events, but it's not reporting those to my client, as far as I can tell.

```cpp
void ScreenUtilitiesLinux::xEventHandler(void* eventPtr) {
    X11::XEvent* event = (X11::XEvent*) eventPtr;

    LOG(Warning, "Got event. {0}", event->type);
    X11::Display* display = X11::XOpenDisplay(NULL);

    if (event->type == ButtonPress) {
        LOG(Warning, "Got MOUSE CLICK event.");
        LinuxPlatform::xEventRecieved.Unbind(xEventHandler); // Unbind the event, we only want to handle one click event.

        X11::XUngrabPointer(display, CurrentTime);
        X11::XCloseDisplay(display);
    } else 
    {
        LOG(Warning, "Got a different event..");
        X11::XCloseDisplay(display);
    }
}

void ScreenUtilitiesLinux::BlockAndReadMouse()
{
    X11::Display* display = X11::XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    X11::Window rootWindow = X11::XRootWindow(display, X11::XDefaultScreen(display));

    X11::Cursor cursor = XCreateFontCursor(display, 130);
    int grabbedPointer = X11::XGrabPointer(display, rootWindow, 0,  ButtonPressMask, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync, rootWindow, cursor, CurrentTime);
    if (grabbedPointer != GrabSuccess) {
        LOG(Error, "Failed to grab cursor for events.");
        return;
    }

    LinuxPlatform::xEventRecieved.Bind(xEventHandler);
}
```

`LinuxPlatform::xEventRecieved` is called every time that the app gets an event that doesn't get filtered. `BlockAndReadMouse` is called when I click a button in the app. When I press the button, I get a few event reports for `LeaveNotify` and `PropertyNotify`. However, I don't get any ButtonPress events, only 8 and and 28 get printed for the "Got event." log.

Does anyone know why the button press events don't get reported? I likely don't understand something about `XGrabPointer` or one of the other X functions I'm trying to use in this code.

BTW, the mouse events DO get blocked. Clicking stops doing anything and I can't scroll anymore, etc.

I've tested a simpler program that does work correctly, and I'm not sure why it does, but mine doesn't, even though mine is using basically the same code, it's really making me wonder what I'm missing..

Comment: Try to use `XOpenDisplay` only once in your code (unless there is a need for more dedicated connections). Btw. for every `XOpenDisplay` there has to be a `XCloseDisplay` call (memory leak).

Comment: @ErdalKüçük yeah thats fair, just calling this code a whole lot, this code is going to change once I get it working, but I need to.. you know.. get it working first. lol

Comment: If you want it to get working, work on a single instance of the display connection.

Comment: @ErdalKüçük oh wait, really? you have to work on a single instance? well that would explain it, lemme try then, I'm sure the large program I'm working on stores a connection. Also yes, I know that I have to have an `XCloseDisplay`, I just forgot to put one there.

Comment: Yes, events are (only) reported to a single client (over the respective connection, see e.g. [XSelectInput](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/XSelectInput.html)).

Comment: I actually didn't realize that `XOpenDisplay` opens another client connection lol

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the issue is because I am opening multiple instances of the `XOpenDisplay` connection. By opening only one instance I was able to get this code to work, which would explain the difference between the more simple program and the program I'm making.